# in a reactjs application made with create-react-app, how do I import js module in a file outside of project directory structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with the following directory structure:

```
/sharedlib
/apps/create-react-reactjs-app-A
/apps/create-react-reactjs-app-B
```

`create-react-reactjs-app-A` and `create-react-reactjs-app-B` are both applications made with create-react-app. I would like both applications to be able to use javascript modules defined in files in a third folder, `sharedlib`. How do I configure my applications to allow them to import modules like this? When I attempt to do so, I get the following exception:

`SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5563 maybe using symlinks will help you

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5563#issuecomment-466025907 might be useful to you.